# Python subprocess with stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use the python subprocess to invoke a third party command `ParseAddress`. The command `ParseAddress` prints out a line of text asking a user to input a list of addresses, then, based on the input it prints out stack trace info. If I manually run the command, it looks like:

```
$ParseAddress Appname                       <- Run the command in console
Paste the addresses - new line to continue
[0]0xaaaaaaaa                               <- a User paste a list of address here
[1]0xbbbbbbbb
[2]0xcccccccc
                                            <- the user type 'enter' to continue
Stack Trace info:                           <-- results of running the ParseAddress
0xaaaaaaaa: Test::info::Runtest
0xbbbbbbbb: Test::info::SingleTestCase
0xcccccccc: ...
```

So, I thought the subprocess() and communicate() would be helpful in this case if I already has a list addresses in text format:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen([ParseAddress, Appname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, error = cmd.communicate(input="[0]0xaaaaaaaa\n[1]0xbbbbbbbb\n[2]0xcccccccc\n\n")
print(output)
```

The when I use the subprocess with communite(), the console output is:

```
$ParseAddress Appname
Paste the addresses - new line to continue
0xaaaaaaaa: ?? ??:0                         <- subprocess.PIPE?
0xbbbbbbbb: ?? ??:0
0xcccccccc: ?? ??:0

Stack Trace info: <-- no results from the ParseAddress since the address info are in incorrect format
```

If I use

```
cmd.communicate(input="[0]0xaaaaaaaa\r\n[1]0xbbbbbbbb\r\n[2]0xcccccccc\r\n\r\n")
```

The result is:

```
$ParseAddress Appname
Paste the addresses - new line to continue
                                           <-- No address here, no ideas why
Stack Trace info:
```

My question is why the parameters are changed from `[0]0xaaaaaaaa` to `0xaaaaaaaa: ?? ??:0`?

What is the correct way to use communication()?

**environment:**
Ubuntu 18.04
Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: Describe what `ParseAddress` and `AppName` refer to. That's a black box that could be doing anything to the input you're providing.

Comment: shouldn't  you be providing `input` be a `bytes` object?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried `output, error = cmd.communicate(input=b"[0]0xaaaaaaaa\n[1]0xbbbbbbbb\n[2]0xcccccccc\n\n")` the result is the same

Comment: @AlexReynolds I updated my question, is it clear for now? Thanks

Comment: Are you reading text? try `universal_newlines=True` at `Popen` arguments, it will make it read the inputs as text instead of binary.

Comment: No, this isn't clear. I still have no idea what this command and its option(s) do. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @geckos, Yes, the input should be text and No, changing `universal_newlines` to `True` not fixing the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you running the process in the same directory and with the same environment as in the terminal?  Also, you might be seeing some `stdout`/`stderr` mixing in that output, but that’s plainly not the data you *sent* or even a corruption of it.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing `subprocess.run(cmd, input="...", text=True)` but the problem is probably unrelated to that. What is the character encoding of your system and the utility you are running? See also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html